# Dificuldade com ClickOnce c# Wpf

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf, clickonce

Tenho uma aplicação e recentemente precisei implementar o WebDriver PhantonJs, que simula um browser porém de forma invisível ao usuário. Na minha aplicação está tudo tudo ok, ele funciona corretamente. O problema ocorre quando preciso exportar meu projeto através do ClickOnce que fica dentro do Visual Studio 2019, após fazer a publicação e colocar para download, o mesmo é atualizado, contudo quando abro a tela que utiliza webdriver, ele da o erro que está faltando o PhantonJS.exe e me solicita que seja feito o download. Segue anexo print do erro, como eu faço para que na publicação ele importe esses arquivos junto para assim a minha tela funcionar igual funciona no ambiente de teste?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Eh possivel que o componente PhantonJS.exe nao esteja presente na publicacao.

Da uma olhada em [Publish] > [Applications File] e verifique no pop up se ele esta marcado como "Include"

Se ele nao estiver aparecendo, marca a opcao "Show All Files"

ps. Marque tambem todos os outros componentes que ele utilizar (dlls, resources, bla bla).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]